# How could text become inserted at the end of my InDesign file without my knowing it?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

I discovered today that the end of my long file has text that appears to be in Spanish or Italian. I did not add text to the end. Did this happen because of a virus or hack? Or did I push a button by accident?

Comment: Sounds like a Latin placeholder. What Scott is saying below. InDesign does not add text by itself, so it must be something you did at some point by accident. Does the text on [this page](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/how-to/add-placeholder-text.html) look like the text you're seeing?

Comment: Yes, it is similar. Latin was my other guess, and I wondered about placeholder text. Thank you for the link, and now I feel better. Thanks for the help so quickly!

Comment: I edited the question, and please note that I accepted an answer on December 4th. I would appreciate it if you could take off the "on hold" for this question. Thank you, and I also thank Scott and Lucian for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Guessing:** Lorem Ipsum text (Latin) which can be inserted by choosing `Type > Insert Placeholder Text`

You most probably mistakenly hit that menu item while working.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I might have hit the shortcut keys and the text was added.

Comment: There is no shortcut key I discovered, but I probably did hit it since it was close to the "Show Hidden Characters" button that I use all the time. Thanks for helping so quickly!